# Must select the good interface name

Tags: java, android, refactoring

What to name the interface **Color**? At Android library have a class with the same name (and this class is used in the application). Would not be good if the app has the class and interface names differ only packages. *ColorInterface* - bad name, how Robert Martin writes in his book "Clean Code".

**update:**

```
interface MyColor {
    Integer toInteger();
    String toString();
}
```

If class implements this interface represents the color in the format *RGB*, *toInteger()* method returns *Color.rgb(red, green, blue)*, and *toString()* method returns, for example, "(10, 20, 30)", where *red = 10, green = 20, blue = 30*.
If class represents the color in the format *ARGB*, *toInteger()* returns *Color.argb(alpha, red, green, blue)*, and *toString()* returns, for example, "(200, 50, 70, 20)".

Comment: `Color` sounds good for me. But it would help to know what methods you want to put in the interface.

Comment: Why not `Colored`? The implementing class isn't necessarily a color, but it *has* a color, so it's colored, right? `Colorable` works, too.

Comment: **Geobits**, "why not Colored"? Because I'm from Russia and unfortunately hardly know English:) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So what you can use same name "Color" , there can be many class of same name in different packages, import one which you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Lucky for you there are two entries in the dictionary for Color.. The other is spelled "Colour".

But by doing this you risk making the great spelling battle worse.

http://www.colourlovers.com/blog/2007/09/05/color-vs-colour-the-great-spelling-battle

http://grammarist.com/spelling/color-colour/